# Is my call intent wrong implemented?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I get the number from user by editText and set as TextView is successful. How i implement the call intent:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.template);

final TextView crdMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.crdMobile);
crdMobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+crdMobile.getText().toString().trim()));
            //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(crdMobile.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent );

        }
    });
```

When I click on crdMobile, normal call interface appears on device. But there is no call being done. After few seconds of holding, call ends with no dialing. How can I improve or correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `ACTION_CALL` you need to hold related permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

I suggest to switch to `ACTION_DIAL` instead anyway, as it does not require any permission and will not exclude your app on devices that feature no telephony like tablets

Comment: Using ACTION_DIAL requires user to press one more click but i think its useful. Thank you.